# How to unparse result after iterating through specific data with papaparse?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, papaparse

I'm trying to use PapaParse to parse a local CSV file and iterate through the JSON in order to only output specific data from the file.

Example: I only want Column "Mill Description" to match adidas && Champion, all other data is discarded.

If you need more clarification don't hesitate to ask, I will be checking here periodically.

CSV File: https://ufile.io/ze7xl

```
papa.parse(file, {
  worker: true,
  header: true,
  transformHeader: true,
  step: function(result) {
    var data = result.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var millDescription = JSON.stringify(data[i]["Mill Description"]);
      if (
        millDescription.includes("adidas") ||
        millDescription.includes("Champion")
      ) {
      // This is where I need help
      }
    }
  },
  complete: function(result, csv) {
    console.log("parsing complete read: ", result, csv); // Nothing is passed to here yet.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 papa.parse(file, {
  worker: true,
  header: true,
  transformHeader: true,
  step: function(result) {
    let data = result.data;
    data = data.filter(d => d["Mill Description"].includes('adidas') || d["Mill Description"].includes('adidaChampions'));
  },
  complete: function(result, csv) {
    console.log("parsing complete read: ", result, csv); // Nothing is passed to here yet.
  }
});
```

Comment: And for unparsing back to csv? I am still confused on an optimal way to do that

Answer (score 0):

The output looks like this, multiple JSON arrays and my question then is how do I unparse all the data to convert back into a csv file?

```
[{
      "Item Number": "B12704533",
      "GTIN Number": "190311332942",
      "Mill Code": "04",
      "Mill Description": "adidas Golf",
      "Style Number": "A262",
      "Mill Style Number": "TWA262S8",
      "Style Name": "AD LADS MICRO STRIPE POLO",
      "Color Code": "53",
      "Color Description": "ROYAL",
      "Size Code": "3",
      "Size Description": "S",
      "Unit Weight": ".7258",
      "Cost": "0",
      "CC": "0",
      "CD": "0",
      "FO": "0",
      "KC": "0",
      "MA": "0",
      "PH": "0",
      "TD": "0",
      "CN": "0",
      "WA": "0",
      "GD": "316",
      "Total Inventory": "316"
    }]
    [{
      "Item Number": "B12704534",
      "GTIN Number": "190311332966",
      "Mill Code": "04",
      "Mill Description": "adidas Golf",
      "Style Number": "A262",
      "Mill Style Number": "TWA262S8",
      "Style Name": "AD LADS MICRO STRIPE POLO",
      "Color Code": "53",
      "Color Description": "ROYAL",
      "Size Code": "4",
      "Size Description": "M",
      "Unit Weight": ".7717",
      "Cost": "0",
      "CC": "0",
      "CD": "0",
      "FO": "0",
      "KC": "0",
      "MA": "0",
      "PH": "0",
      "TD": "1",
      "CN": "0",
      "WA": "0",
      "GD": "540",
      "Total Inventory": "541"
    }]
```